# Custom cell in tableView issue

Tags: iphone, tableview, cell

I am trying to create a custom cell through the following code below in my TableView. I am 100% new to Objective C and Iphone development so I am far away from experienced.

On the following code: **cell.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];** it says (Property 'label1' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell':

What have I missed? All the relevant code can be found below. Thanx for all the help / beginner

**BookmarksViewController.h**

```
@interface BookmarksViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *items;

UILabel *label1;
UILabel *label2;
UILabel *label3;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label3;

- (NSMutableArray*) getStoredItems;
- (void) clearItems;
- (void) removeItemWithId:(int)itemId;

@end
```

**BookmarksViewController.m**

```
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"

@interface BookmarksViewController ()

@end

@implementation BookmarksViewController

@synthesize items;
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
@synthesize label2 = _label2;
@synthesize label3 = _label3;



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BookmarkCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    CGRect labelFrame = cell.bounds;
    labelFrame.size.height= labelFrame.size.height * 0.5;

    cell.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];

}
Bookmark *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *chunks = [item.name componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *name;
NSString *book;
NSString *chapter;

if ([chunks count] > 0)
{
    name = [chunks objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([chunks count] > 1)
    {
        book = [chunks objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([chunks count] > 2)
        {
            chapter = [chunks objectAtIndex:2];
        }
    }
}

cell.label1.text = name;

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 70; // height of tableView Cell
}
```

Comment: you created label1 as a property of the BookmarksViewController class, not the UITableViewCell class.  Also, if you want to create a custom cell, you should usually create a custom cell class as a subclass of UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row] ;
    UILabel *lblTitle = nil;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        lblTitle =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 320, 44)];
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        lblTitle.tag = 1;

        UILabel *lblType =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 320, 44)];
        lblType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblType.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        lblType.tag = 2;

        UILabel *lblDate =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 40, 320, 44)];
        lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        lblDate.tag = 3;

        UILabel *lblTime =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, 20, 320, 44)];
        lblTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTime.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        lblTime.tag = 4;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblType];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDate];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTime];

    }

    lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];


    [lblTitle setText:@""];



    UILabel *lblType = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    [lblType setText:@""];

    UILabel *lblDate = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    [lblDate setText:@""];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the labels to the cell, as the cell itself doesn't have a label1 property, etc -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } else { // if there is already a subview, remove it
    while ([[cell.contentView subviews] count] > 0) {
        UIView *labelToClear = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [labelToClear removeFromSuperview];
    }
    }

    UILabel *myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 400, 30)] autorelease];

    // set up myLabel here

    [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];


    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code:

```
label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
```

instead of `cell.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];`

and also `label1.text = name;` instead of `cell.label1.text = name;`

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have to do for this:
1. Create custom classes (.h and .m) of subclass UITableViewCell.
2. Then in your storyboard give classname of the tableview cell as the created class.
3. Now you can design the cell and connect outlets in the created custom class.
4. Also don't forget to give reuse identifier of cell in storyboard.
5. Now in CellForRowAtIndexPath method you need to write folowing code:

-

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    YourCustomClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourReuseIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[YourCustomClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"YourReuseIdentifier"];
    }


cell.yourLabel.text = cell.cityNameLbl.text.capitalizedString;
return cell;
```

}